# $(window).load() with ajax inside

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to retrieve all the data inside the database when the page is loaded but when I try to click the refresh button nothing was returned, do you have any idea why? Here is my code:

```
      $(window).load(function (){
        $.ajax({                
            url: 'get.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data){
               $.each(data, function(i,item) {
                 $('#info').append("<p> you are:"+data[i].username+"</p> <p> your  message  is:"+data[i].msg);
               })
             }
        });


      });
```

Comment: Does your success function fire (using `console.log` or `alert`)? You should also add an error handler.

Comment: Did you look in our net panel to see if the AJAX call was even made? Did you check your console, are there any errors? Hitting the refresh button and noticing that the screen is blank is only the first clue.

Comment: this what my console said POST http://localhost/feeds/get.php 200 OK 63ms. dunno why it is not appearing

Comment: And what does `data` contain?

Comment: this is what the console said
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: username in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\feeds\get.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: msg in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\feeds\get.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
[{"username":"heyt","msg":"asdad","counter":1}]

Comment: @Aoi M. Serizawa so the problem is with the php, not the js. You need to post the contents of `get.php`.

Comment: Agree with @jeroen, please paste get.php code

Comment: here it is my complete code http://pastebin.com/BmATXMmS

Comment: yes there is because at first the 
$username = $_POST['username'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];

dont have anything on them yet. isnt?

Comment: i dont see any. whats ur answer again?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17141/discussion-between-gbd-and-aoi-m-serizawa)

Comment: if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['msg'])){
  $username = $_POST['username'];

  $msg = $_POST['msg'];
}

Comment: GBD my isp had an maintenance on my internet.. hope u can still help me.. this is the paste bin that u were askin for b4 my connection got cut. http://pastebin.com/D0TJVqV7

Comment: Ok. i formatted your html code. here you go: http://pastebin.com/1Zdyaxun

Comment: it keeps on iterating the previous row when i clicked the submit button thats why my idea is to load the $('#info') when the submit is clicked. thats why on my previous code i put the $(window).load inside the submit but i guess it didnt work..

Comment: so you want append on newly added row after submit to your list ?

Comment: keep html as it is i have formatted. and then change your php code like this http://pastebin.com/F8VKQzWr

Comment: i have a question GBD. why du u have a select in like #16 and yet u also have it in #35 kindly explain plsss... http://pastebin.com/F8VKQzWr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New answer posted here.

Change your php code as below

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['msg'])){
  $username = $_POST['username'];

  $msg = $_POST['msg'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like the ajax is not returning before the function gets executed.

Edit:

```
   $(window).load(function (){
      $.ajax({                
        url: 'get.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST', //u missed this line.
        success: function (data){
          var data_new = jQuery.parseJSON(data);     
          $.each(data_new, function(i, item) {
           $('#info').append("<p> you are:" + data_new.username +"</p> <p> your  message   is:"+data_new.msg);
           });

         }
    });


  });
```

Comment: No, it's not the same: `$(document).ready` fires when the DOM is loaded, `$(window).load` fires after that when all images / assets have been loaded as well.

Comment: i added the type:'POST' still nothing happen

Comment: try debugging inside the callback function to see if the ajax is working fine.